# Is the ellipsis made in the following sentence fine?

Tags: ellipses

> The point is way more clear in the first scenario than it is in the second.

Is there any problem that I omitted "scenario" after the second?

I could also say this way:

> The point is way more clear in the first scenario than it is in the second **one**.

But the first way seems better to me as it has more brevity.

Comment: This doesn't relate to your question directly, but a more grammatical and less informal wording of "way more clear" would be "much clearer".

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right.  You could also express the idea as

> The point is way more clear in the first scenario than it is in the
>   second scenario.

This is an undeniably clunky sentence (see The Elements of Style).  Omission of the second "scenario" or "one" does not introduce any ambiguity into the thought, so it would generally be considered the better option to eliminate those extraneous words.